# ServerSocket times out and exits server program

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm trying to implement a server that accepts connections but times out and **closes that specific connection only** if it hasn't received anything from that connection after N milliseconds.

From my possible misunderstanding of `ServerSocket`'s `setSoTimeout(int milliseconds)` method, I thought this behaviour could be accomplished by passing N to `setSoTimeout`.

What I'm experiencing is once a client makes a connection, and doesn't send anything over that connection for N seconds, the server catches a `SocketTimeoutException`, but then completely stops execution and ends the process running the server program. Here is my server's `listen` method:

```
    private static void listen() throws IOException {
    while(true) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            Connection connexion = new Connection(clientSocket);
            connexion.start();  
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
        }           
    } 
}
```

I successfully catch the `SocketTimeoutException`, ignore it (bad I know!) and assume that the client connection that caused the exception gets closed. Then I just break out of the catch block to continue accepting other client connections. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `continue;` instead of `break;` in the `try-catch` clause. The server will keep listening.

Answer (score 0):

> assume that the client connection that caused the exception gets closed.

Incorrect assumption. The `accept()` is what has timed out. The client connection hasn't done anything yet.

> Then I just break out of the catch block to continue accepting other client connections.

Err, no, you break out of the catch block to *stop* accepting other client connections. You're breaking out of the accept loop.

> What am I missing here?

A `continue` instead of a `break`.

If you don't care about the `SocketTimeoutException` why are you setting a socket timeout on the `ServerSocket`? Just remove that.

Comment: Is there a way I can set a timeout on the client `Socket` then? Is there a method on the `Socket` class that would allow me to achieve my desired functionality?

Comment: Yes, err, `setSoTimeout()`, the same one you called on the `ServerSocket`. Did you even look?

Comment: My bad, I must have missed seeing `Socket`'s `setSoTimeout` method; I thought it was only available for `ServerSocket`. Thanks again for your informative answer @EJP